# What does linearization do in MATLAB's PID tuner?

Tags: matlab, control-theory

I noticed that the PID tuner from MATLAB has a linearizatin step before tuning.
What does this linearization step do?
And why we have to linearize a model in PID tuning?

Comment: You might have a better of getting an answer on other sites, maybe the stack exchange of signal processing or robotics. I am not familiar with the PID tuner in MATLAB, but linearization would enable you to calculate the Fourier transform of the system and possibly with the use of eigen values tune the PID.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to clarify:

1. PID Tuner algorithm works on linear time-invariant models.
2. PID Tuner app in MATLAB does not do linearization. You provide it with a transfer function of a plant model, and it calculates PID gains.
3. On the other hand, when you press "Tune" button inside of a PID Controller block in Simulink, PID Tuner first needs to obtain a transfer function to use for tuning PID Controller gains. This step of obtaining a transfer function from a generally non-linear Simulink model is linearization. If you want to learn more about linearization in Simulink, please visit this page on [linearization](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/linearization.html).